# Unexpected termination of SSIS when calling it from a stored procedure initiated by a C# service

Tags: c#, t-sql, ssis

I have a controller that calls a WebAPI service.  I want this service to asynchronously call a stored procedure that executes an SSIS package.  Ideally I don't want the service to wait at all for the stored procedure to finish executing the SSIS package.  However, if it does have to wait, I need to ensure that there won't be any timeout issues.  My issue is that I frequently get "unexpected termination" error in SSIS. Can anyone help me figure out any other options to prevent the "unexpected termination" error.  Also, is there a better way to achieve the asynchronous call.

Here is my service (Web API) repository code:

```
  public void PublishSchedule(DateTime scheduleDate, productId)
    {

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartProcedure(scheduleDate, productId)));              

    }    

    public static void StartProcedure(DateTime scheduleDate, string productId)
    {
        var ssisPkgEntities = new ExportFlightDataSPEntities();

            try
            {
                var cs = new SqlConnection(ssisPkgEntities.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("bridge.ExportFlightData", cs);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productId;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ScheduleDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = scheduleDate.ToString();

                //Setup Output result message paramater
                var parm = new SqlParameter("@returnResult", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10000) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

                cs.Open();

                var result = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();                                          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Errors
            }

    }
```

Here is the t-sql in the stored procedure that executes the SSIS package:

```
        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
                @package_name=N'ExportFligthData.dtsx',     --SSIS package name TABLE:(SELECT * FROM [SSISDB].internal.packages)
                @folder_name=N'UCLToVOD', --Folder were the package lives TABLE:(SELECT * FROM [SSISDB].internal.folders)
                @project_name=N'UCLToVOD',--Project name were SSIS package lives TABLE:(SELECT * FROM [SSISDB].internal.projects)
                @use32bitruntime=FALSE, 
                @reference_id=NULL,             --Environment reference, if null then no environment configuration is applied.
                @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT   --The paramter is outputed and contains the execution_id of your SSIS execution context.


        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
                @execution_id,  
                @object_type=50, 
                @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', 
                @parameter_value=1; -- true


        -- Set our package parameters
        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
                @execution_id,  
                @object_type=50, 
                @parameter_name=N'DUMP_ON_EVENT', 
                @parameter_value=1; -- true

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
                @execution_id,  
                @object_type=50, 
                @parameter_name=N'DUMP_EVENT_CODE', 
                @parameter_value=N'0x80040E4D;0x80004005';

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
                @execution_id,  
                @object_type=50, 
                @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', 
                @parameter_value= 1; -- Basic

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
                @execution_id,  
                @object_type=50, 
                @parameter_name=N'CALLER_INFO', 
                @parameter_value= N'ExportFlightData';

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
                @execution_id,  
                @object_type=50, 
                @parameter_name=N'DUMP_ON_ERROR', 
                @parameter_value=1; -- true

        /* Actual SSIS Parameters */
        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
                @execution_id,  
                @object_type=30, 
                @parameter_name=N'ProductId', 
                @parameter_value=@productId

        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
            @execution_id,  
            @object_type=30,
            @parameter_name=N'ScheduleDate', 
            @parameter_value=@ScheduleDate



        -- Start the package
        EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] 
                @execution_id;

        --The status of the operation. The possible values are created (1), running (2), canceled (3), failed (4), pending (5), ended unexpectedly (6), succeeded (7), stopping (8), and completed (9).
        --select * from [SSISDB].[catalog].[executions] where execution_id = @execution_id;

        SELECT @resultStatus = status, @resultMsgSourceName = message_source_name, @resultMessage = message
           FROM [SSISDB].catalog.executions e
           JOIN [SSISDB].catalog.event_messages em
             ON e.execution_id = em.operation_id
            AND event_name = 'OnError'
          WHERE e.execution_id = @execution_id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute packages asynchronously by setting a parameter:

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
        @execution_id,  -- execution_id from catalog.create_execution
        @object_type=50, 
        @parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', 
        @parameter_value= 0;
```

There is some info on that [here](http://www.ssistalk.com/2012/07/24/quick-tip-run-ssis-2012-packages-synchronously-and-other-execution-options/)

Comment: I forgot to mention, there is also the ability to execute packages via .net, which would probably be cleaner in your situation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Setting the "SYNCHRONIZED" parameter was my issue.  Once I took this out, I got the behavior that I desired.